# Define value edit by another php file

Tags: php, performance, oracle

I have 2 questions

1.) how to write `update_defile($array_value){...}` function?

define_file.php

```
<?php
  define("FIST_NAME", "something1");
  define("LAST_NAME", "something2");
  define("ADDRESS", "something3");
?>
```

"something" is not a constant value that can be change every method `Call(update_defile($array_value)`

value set

```
$array_value = ("FIST_NAMe" => "duleep", "LAST_NAME" => "dissnayaka", "AGE" => "28" );
```

after call method(update_defile($array_value){.....}) "define_file.php"
file want to be look like bellow

```
<?php
  define("FIST_NAME", "duleep");
  define("LAST_NAME", "dissnayaka");
  define("ADDRESS", "something3");
  define("AGE", "28");
?>
```

2).

My datbase is Oracle. I already saved configuration value in the data base but frequently use these configuration value for my application. So i get value form database and save in the define_file.php as increase performance(down rate database call) but I'm not sure i can increase performance keep configuration value in the PHP file please explain. what is the best way increase performance my application and other alternative solutions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public function update($form_config_arr)
   {

      if( (is_readable($config_file_path)) && is_writable($config_file_path))
      {
         if(!$config_old_file_content = file_get_contents($config_file_path))
         {
            throw new Exception('Unable to open file!');
         }

         $i = 0;
         $config_old_arr = array();
         $config_new_arr = array();

         foreach ($form_config_arr as $constant => $value){
            $config_old_line = $this->getLine($constant);
            $config_old_arr[$i] = $config_old_line;

            if(($value == 'true') || ($value == 'false')){
               $config_new_arr[$i] = "define ( '$constant', $value );\n";
            }else{
               $config_new_arr[$i] = "define ( '$constant', '$value' );\n";
            }
            $i++;
         }

         $config_new_file_content = str_replace($config_old_arr, $config_new_arr, $config_old_file_content);
         $new_content_file_write = file_put_contents($config_file_path, $config_new_file_content);

         foreach ($config_new_arr as $constant => $value)
         {
            echo $value.'<br/>';
         }
         return true;
      }else{
         throw new Exception('Access denied for '.$config_file_path);
         return false;
      }

   }

   /**
    *
    * @param string $constant
    * @return string
    */
   private function getLine($constant)
   {
      $match_line = '';
      $config_file = fopen($config_file_path, "r");
      if($config_file)
      {
         //Output a line of the file until the end is reached
         $i = 0;
         while(!feof($config_file))
         {
            $i++;
            $config_old_line = fgets($config_file);
            $pos = strpos($config_old_line, $constant);
            if( $pos !== false )
            {
               $match_line= $config_old_line;
            }
         }
         fclose($config_file);
         return $match_line;
      }else{
         throw new Exception('Unable to open file!');
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why cant u use session to store such values , then u can access and modify from anywhere 
in the script.

```
<?php
    session_start();
     $_SESSION["FIST_NAME"]= "something1";
    $_SESSION["LAST_NAME"]= "something2";
    $_SESSION["ADDRESS"]= "something3";


?>
```

Comment: that's good idea but define_file.php file have more than 200 variables. so i feel session can't handle that kind of memory. any way thanks your feed back

Comment: actually define is used for constants then u shouldn't change it once set during run time.

Comment: sure my main idea want to create configuration file for per web application. Every customer has separate configuration file

Comment: if u are using zend framework you can use zend registry class to accomplish this task.

Comment: u can write a simple one using a singleton class using php.

Comment: i already wrote method but that method is not perfect that method only change already exit define values

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is edit a file.
Simply create another php script: updater.php
It should poll the database, fetch the values and update the values in define_file.php

Look for php file handling functions here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp

Comment: but my client need single location to keep their configuration values that main reason for edit define_file.php file